# Hanlder blocks TextView change

Tags: java, android

Running the following code should make a textView change before the handler finishes. However the textview changes after the handler finishes. Is the handler somehow avoiding befores text change?

```
    t.setText("Test!"); 
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        }
    },1000);
```

Comment: Just move setText code inside run.

Comment: The thing i wanna do is change the text, wait 1 second and keep on with the rest of the code - I dont wanna change the textView after one second, wanna change it before

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

Whatever code you written inside run it will executed after you given interval time(1000).

**Note :** you have to declare you textview or any other view which you wan to use inside run outside onCreate() or at class level.

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
      t.setText("Test!"); 
  }
},1000);
```